# Reference request for Poincaré–Lefschetz duality as an intersection pairing

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

I believe the following is well known after talking to some experts, but I am unable to find a reference for the case with boundary.

Fix a field $F$ and an oriented $n$-manifold $(M,\partial M)$. We have a pairing $H_*(M) \otimes H_{n-*}(M,\partial M) \rightarrow F$ given by taking transverse representatives of the cycles and counting the oriented intersections.

**Claim:** This pairing is the same as the Poincaré–Lefschetz duality pairing.

Is there a standard reference for this? Or at least an argument that is only a few lines, possibly relying on the closed version of the statement?

Comment: The proof of the  statement is fairly direct from the old-fashioned PL triangulations approach to the proof (i.e. Poincare's approach).   When using singular homology the proof is more subtle. Bredon's "Geometry and Topology" is a good source.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thanks Ryan; it seems like 11.10 is the best Bredon has for non-submanifolds in which he concludes there is some geometric intersection of subspaces if there is a nontrivial cup product.

Comment: Right, Bredon is concerned about Steenrod realizability.  For the pairing on all homology classes perhaps there isn't a write-up beyond the classical Poincare perspective.   That said, I must be wrong -- perhaps the work of Greg Friedman is where to look? https://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/

Comment: The theorem you are looking for is Theorem 95.15 in my lecture notes:  https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/1at-uptodate.pdf

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you; if I understand correctly Theorem 8.5.10 in his "Singular Intersection Homology" gives the intended result.

Comment: @StefanFriedl Thanks for the notes; if I understand your theorem it won't apply for an arbitrary cycle since thickening it to a manifold will not yield an embedding with the correct conditions on the boundary.

Comment: sorry, I should have referred to Theorem 95.14.

Comment: @StefanFriedl Well that certainly seems to answer my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proven for smooth manifolds by Goresky in "Whitney Stratified Chains and Cochains".